# Operation timed out Ansible AWS

Tags: ansible

In etc/ansible/hosts, I have entered VPC IPv4 and tried to run command:

> ansible all -m ping

but got this error.

UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host ***.***.***.*** port 22: Operation timed out\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}

please help to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you entered the `public` DNS entry? Can you run `ping` on command line? If `Unix` ping command is not working there is no need to try `Ansible` ping command.

For the Ansible `ping` command it is also necessary to configure ssh access as the `Ansible` ping command is only related to the `Unix` ping command by name.

The `Ansible` ping command works like the most Ansible modules. It will copy and execute a Python script to and on the target system. In case of the ping module it will copy and execute a script which returns `pong`.

In summary: The ping command ensures that:

- network access is working
- SSH access is working
- and that the Python installation on the target system is sufficient for Ansible